# Preserving special chars using osgeo.ogr.Driver to shapefile in Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, kml, ogr, encoding

I am converting KML files to shapefiles and run in to the problem that special characters are not preserved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, ogr, osgeo, sys


ogr.UseExceptions() 
# ...
shp_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
# String with file name called outpolyext:
outpolys_file = shp_driver.CreateDataSource( outpolyext )
outpolys_layer = outpolys_file.CreateLayer("polys", srs=srs, geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
outpolys_layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('Name', ogr.OFTString))
# Left out other fields I created above
# ...
kmldr = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
datasource = kmldr.Open(kml_file)
# Create new feature "feature" for shapefile 
# with new field names:
ftd = outpolys_layer.GetLayerDefn()
feature = ogr.Feature(ftd)
# ...
# Get first layer from KML, loop through each 
# KML feature called "f", then:
print(f.items())
feature.SetField("Name", f.GetField('Name')) 
feature.SetGeometry(multipolys)
outpolys_layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

In the original KML file, I have e.g. the following value "bæk/sti", the special chars in the resulting shapefile end up blank.

In the terminal print(f.items()) results in:

```
{'Name': 'b\xc3\xa6k/sti', 'Description': ''}
```

Can anyone see where it goes wrong - already when reading the KML file or later when saving to the shapefile - or somewhere in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! An environment variable needs to be set. It can be set either in the shell:

```
export SHAPE_ENCODING="utf-8"
```

or within the script:

```
os.environ['SHAPE_ENCODING'] = "utf-8"
```

I prefer to set it in the script.

I tried out various ways of decoding from utf-8 and encoding to ISO8859_1 within the script with no luck. feature.SetField does not accept a unicode value, must be char.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Python encodings...

The first line of a KML file indicates the character encoding (XML encoding declaration)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

In [GDAL: KML - Keyhole Markup Language](http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html)

> The content returned by OGR will be encoded in UTF-8, after the conversion from the encoding mentioned in the file header is.

With Python 2.7.x

```
from osgeo import ogr
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
ds_in = drv.Open('test.kml')
for kml_lyr in ds_in:
    for feat in kml_lyr:
        record = feat.items()

record
{'Name': 'b\xc3\xa6k/sti', 'Description': ''}
record['Name']
'b\xc3\xa6k/sti'
type(record['Name'])
<type 'str'>
# but
 print record['Name']
 bæk/sti
```

Therefore the result of ogr is a unicode-encoded string and not a pure unicode string (for the differences look at [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) or [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html))

```
u'bæk/sti'
u'b\xe6k/sti'
type(u'bæk/sti')
<type 'unicode'>
print u'bæk/sti'
bæk/sti
# and
u"b\xe6k/sti".encode('utf-8')
'b\xc3\xa6k/sti' # -> the result
type(u"b\xe6k/sti".encode('utf-8'))
<type 'str'>
```

Compare with

```
import xmltodict as xmltodict
file = file('test.kml')
o = xmltodict.parse(file)
o['kml']['Document']['Folder']['Placemark']['name']
u'b\xe6k/sti'
print o['kml']['Document']['Folder']['Placemark']['name']
bæk/sti
```

In Python 3.x all the strings are sequences of unicode characters so

```
from osgeo import ogr
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
ds_in = drv.Open('test.kml')
for kml_lyr in ds_in:
    for feat in kml_lyr:
        record = feat.items()
record
{'Description': '', 'Name': 'bæk/sti'}
recode['Name']
'bæk/sti'
type(record['Name'])
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that the the values loaded from the kml file are utf-8 encoded (as is the file) and there is a method on the string to convert to unicode: `n2 = f.GetField('Name').decode('utf-8')`, `type(n2)` returns `'unicode'`. From the docs I deduct that shape is also utf-8 by default. If not, is there a way to set the file to utf-8 encoding as I see that as preferable over e.g. 'ascii' or similar?

Comment: I was wrong about the default encoding of shape files. Default is ISO8859_1.